# Viewing pdfs with vim latex-suite: !start Preview shell returned 127

Tags: vim

I have Mac OS X Lion, vim 7.3, and latex-suite.  With a minimal .tex file I can compile a pdf from within vim using \ll.  However I can't view the pdf with \lv.  The [FAQ](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=faq&title=FAQ) suggests that I check whether or not I can open my pdf viewer from inside vim with

!start Preview

However when I do this I get the message

shell returned 127.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `!open -a Preview` to open Preview.

Here is my settings to make `<leader>lv` work for me:

```
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_TreatMacViewerAsUNIX = 1
let g:Tex_ExecuteUNIXViewerInForeground = 1
let g:Tex_ViewRule_ps = 'open -a Skim'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'open -a /Applications/Skim.app'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_dvi = 'open -a /Applications/texniscope.app'
```

Note that I am using [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net) instead of Preview as PDF viewer here. You can simply put:

```
let g:Tex_ViewRule_ps = 'open -a Preview'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'open -a Preview'
```

to view the resulting postscript or PDF file with Preview.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been trying to fix this for a long time.

Comment: I had to set the following in my `.vimrc` to get `<leader>lv` to work correctly:

    `autocmd FileType tex call Tex_SetTeXCompilerTarget('View','pdf')`                                                                                                                     
hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in this file `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` works for me

```
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_TreatMacViewerAsUNIX = 1
let g:Tex_ExecuteUNIXViewerInForeground = 1
let g:Tex_ViewRule_ps = 'open -a Skim'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'open -a /Applications/Skim.app'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_dvi = 'open -a /Applications/texniscope.app'
```